# Can an Unbounded Sequence Always be Partitioned into Bounded and Growing to Infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(\alpha_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ which is unbounded and contains a bounded subsequence. Does there exist two strictly monotone functions $\phi,\lambda:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ **which partition $\mathbb{N}$** such that $(\alpha_{\phi_n})$ is bounded and $(\alpha_{\lambda_n})\rightarrow\infty?$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The title question is different from the body question and has a different answer. What is your real question?

Comment: @user14111 The body question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume you want the two monotone functions to form a partition then the answer is no.

Define the sequence $a_n=\max(k|\exists a, a^k=n)$.

This sequence clearly meets the initial requirements, but it cannot be partitioned in the desired way. This can be seen as any number occurs infinitely often in the sequence.

If the two functions do not need to form a partition the answer is yes as we can take the bounded subsequence that was assumed to exist and the sequence $\alpha_{b_n}$ where $b_n=min(k|\alpha_k>\alpha_{b_{n-1}})$.

Comment: I'm not sure this disproves my conjecture. Your index $b_n$ will be strictly monotone (which I don't require), and it's not clear to me that it's the "largest" subsequence going to infinity.

Comment: @MilesGould What is your conjecture? The first half answers the title question with a no and the second half answers the body question with a yes. Your question does require that $b_n$ is strictly monotone (or $\lambda_n$ as you phrased it) and you never mentioned that you wanted it to be the "largest" subsequence going to infinity so I didn't try to do that. I don't even know what that means in this context as the only interpretation I can think of is in terms of partitions which the first half answers.

Comment: I'm happy to try to help if anything I have written is confusing or you think I have made a mistake, but I don't know what you want.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say that the $(a_{b_n})$ is strictly monotone, which I didn't require. You could imagine a $(b_n')$  which has $a_{b_n'}\rightarrow\infty$ and $b'(\mathbb{N})\not\subseteq b(\mathbb{N})$

Comment: Oh my gosh, I just realized I forgot to say that $\phi,\lambda$ partition $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @MilesGould I am aware that $\alpha_{b_n}$ need not be strictly monotone, it was actually due to laziness that I made it strictly monotone. Now that the question has been updated to include the fact that the two subsequences partition $\Bbb{N}$ the first half of the answer demonstrates a counterexample showing that the answer is no. I can write up a proof of that fact if it would help.

Comment: I apologize. Complete brain malfunction. I will accept your answer and I have edited the question.

Comment: @MilesGould Don't worry about it. I might write up a full proof that the sequence I gave is a counterexample in a bit if I have time.